# Faceting chart by a column "category"

Tags: powerbi, visualization, powerbi-desktop, vega-lite, deneb

I have a working bar-chart. I´d like to add an column "categories", which has 8 different values. The barchart should be faceted by the category, so that 8 different charts are shown.

current barchart (without the new column):

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
     "data": {
    "values": [
    {"Percent": 0.612,"Team": "ALL", "type": "total", "ID": "1", "SortOrder": "1", "color": "#005CA9"},
  {"Percent": 0.251,"Team": "ALL", "type": "part", "ID": "1", "SortOrder": "2", "color": "#86C2EB"},
  {"Percent": 0.803,"Team": "Team A", "type": "total", "ID": "2", "SortOrder": "1", "color": "#005CA9"},
  {"Percent": 0.189,"Team": "Team A", "type": "part", "ID": "2", "SortOrder": "2", "color": "#86C2EB"},
  {"Percent": 0.691,"Team": "Team B", "type": "total", "ID": "3", "SortOrder": "1", "color": "#005CA9"},
  {"Percent": 0.255,"Team": "Team B", "type": "part", "ID": "3", "SortOrder": "2", "color": "#86C2EB"},
  {"Percent": 0.019,"Team": "Team C", "type": "total", "ID": "4", "SortOrder": "1", "color": "#005CA9"},
  {"Percent": 0.37,"Team": "Team C", "type": "part", "ID": "4", "SortOrder": "2", "color": "#86C2EB"}

    ]},
   
  "transform": [
    {
      "calculate": "1 * 0",
      "as": "Zero"
    },
    {"calculate": "1 * 1", "as": "One"}
  ],
 
  
  "encoding": {
    "y": {
      "field": "Team",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "axis": null,
      "sort": {
        "op": "sum",
        "field": "ID",
        "order": "ascending"
      }
    }
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "name": "BackgroundBAR",
      "mark": {
        "type": "bar",
        "color": "#DEE2E6",
        "height": 5,
        "cornerRadiusEnd": 4,
        "yOffset": 10
      },
      "encoding": {
        
        "x": {
          "field": "One",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "axis": {
            "title": null,
            "offset": 10,
            "tickCount": 5,
            "format": "0.0%"
          },
          "stack": false
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "BAR",
      "mark": {
        "type": "bar",
        "height": 5,
        "cornerRadiusEnd": 4,
        "yOffset": 10
      },
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "Percent",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "axis": null,
          "stack": true,
          "sort": {
            "op": "sum",
            "field": "SortOrder",
            "order": "ascending"
          }
        },
        "color": {
          "field": "type",
          "scale": {
            "range": {"field": "color"}
          },
          "type": "nominal",
          "legend": {
            "orient": "bottom",
            "title": null
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "text",
      "mark": {
        "type": "text",
        "align": "left",
        "color": "#005CA9",
        "font": "Segoe UI",
        "fontSize": 10,
        "fontStyle": "normal",
        "fontWeight": "bold"
      },
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "Zero",
          "type": "quantitative"
        },
        "text": {
          "field": "Team",
          "type": "nominal"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "DATA_LABEL",
      "mark": {
        "type": "text",
        "color": "#005CA9",
        "align": "left",
        "fontSize": 8,
        "font": "Segoe UI",
        "fontStyle": "normal",
        "fontWeight": "bold",
        "xOffset": 5,
        "yOffset": 20
      },
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "Percent",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "stack": true
        },
        "color": {
          "field": "type",
          "type": "nominal",
          "legend": {"orient": "bottom"}
        },
        "text": {
          "field": "Percent",
          "format": "0.0%"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
  
   
}
```

the new chart, with the added column:
if have tried "facet": {"row": {"field": "Category"}}, next to data or in the encoding, but it didn´t work

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
     "data": {
    "values": [
{"Percent": 0.001,"Team": "ALL", "type": "total", "ID": "1", "SortOrder": "1", "color": "#005CA9","Category": "AH"},
{"Percent": 0.001,"Team": "ALL", "type": "total", "ID": "1", "SortOrder": "1", "color": "#005CA9","Category": "FLV"},
{"Percent": 0.247,"Team": "ALL", "type": "total", "ID": "1", "SortOrder": "1", "color": "#005CA9","Category": "KFZ"},
{"Percent": 0.056,"Team": "ALL", "type": "total", "ID": "1", "SortOrder": "1", "color": "#005CA9","Category": "KV"},
{"Percent": 0.03,"Team": "ALL", "type": "total", "ID": "1", "SortOrder": "1", "color": "#005CA9","Category": "LV"},
{"Percent": 0.044,"Team": "ALL", "type": "total", "ID": "1", "SortOrder": "1", "color": "#005CA9","Category": "RS"},
{"Percent": 0.17,"Team": "ALL", "type": "total", "ID": "1", "SortOrder": "1", "color": "#005CA9","Category": "SV"},
{"Percent": 0.064,"Team": "ALL", "type": "total", "ID": "1", "SortOrder": "1", "color": "#005CA9","Category": "UV"},
{"Percent": 0.001,"Team": "ALL", "type": "part", "ID": "1", "SortOrder": "2", "color": "#86C2EB","Category": "AH"},
{"Percent": 0.001,"Team": "ALL", "type": "part", "ID": "1", "SortOrder": "2", "color": "#86C2EB","Category": "FLV"},
{"Percent": 0.067,"Team": "ALL", "type": "part", "ID": "1", "SortOrder": "2", "color": "#86C2EB","Category": "KFZ"},
{"Percent": 0.042,"Team": "ALL", "type": "part", "ID": "1", "SortOrder": "2", "color": "#86C2EB","Category": "KV"},
{"Percent": 0.015,"Team": "ALL", "type": "part", "ID": "1", "SortOrder": "2", "color": "#86C2EB","Category": "LV"},
{"Percent": 0.013,"Team": "ALL", "type": "part", "ID": "1", "SortOrder": "2", "color": "#86C2EB","Category": "RS"},
{"Percent": 0.077,"Team": "ALL", "type": "part", "ID": "1", "SortOrder": "2", "color": "#86C2EB","Category": "SV"},
{"Percent": 0.036,"Team": "ALL", "type": "part", "ID": "1", "SortOrder": "2", "color": "#86C2EB","Category": "UV"},
{"Percent": 0.001,"Team": "Team A", "type": "total", "ID": "2", "SortOrder": "1", "color": "#005CA9","Category": "AH"},
{"Percent": 0.002,"Team": "Team A", "type": "total", "ID": "2", "SortOrder": "1", "color": "#005CA9","Category": "FLV"},
{"Percent": 0.306,"Team": "Team A", "type": "total", "ID": "2", "SortOrder": "1", "color": "#005CA9","Category": "KFZ"},
{"Percent": 0.081,"Team": "Team A", "type": "total", "ID": "2", "SortOrder": "1", "color": "#005CA9","Category": "KV"},
{"Percent": 0.048,"Team": "Team A", "type": "total", "ID": "2", "SortOrder": "1", "color": "#005CA9","Category": "LV"},
{"Percent": 0.057,"Team": "Team A", "type": "total", "ID": "2", "SortOrder": "1", "color": "#005CA9","Category": "RS"},
{"Percent": 0.215,"Team": "Team A", "type": "total", "ID": "2", "SortOrder": "1", "color": "#005CA9","Category": "SV"},
{"Percent": 0.093,"Team": "Team A", "type": "total", "ID": "2", "SortOrder": "1", "color": "#005CA9","Category": "UV"},
{"Percent": 0.001,"Team": "Team A", "type": "part", "ID": "2", "SortOrder": "2", "color": "#86C2EB","Category": "AH"},
{"Percent": 0.001,"Team": "Team A", "type": "part", "ID": "2", "SortOrder": "2", "color": "#86C2EB","Category": "FLV"},
{"Percent": 0.055,"Team": "Team A", "type": "part", "ID": "2", "SortOrder": "2", "color": "#86C2EB","Category": "KFZ"},
{"Percent": 0.028,"Team": "Team A", "type": "part", "ID": "2", "SortOrder": "2", "color": "#86C2EB","Category": "KV"},
{"Percent": 0.01,"Team": "Team A", "type": "part", "ID": "2", "SortOrder": "2", "color": "#86C2EB","Category": "LV"},
{"Percent": 0.012,"Team": "Team A", "type": "part", "ID": "2", "SortOrder": "2", "color": "#86C2EB","Category": "RS"},
{"Percent": 0.056,"Team": "Team A", "type": "part", "ID": "2", "SortOrder": "2", "color": "#86C2EB","Category": "SV"},
{"Percent": 0.026,"Team": "Team A", "type": "part", "ID": "2", "SortOrder": "2", "color": "#86C2EB","Category": "UV"},
{"Percent": 0.001,"Team": "Team B", "type": "total", "ID": "3", "SortOrder": "1", "color": "#005CA9","Category": "AH"},
{"Percent": 0.001,"Team": "Team B", "type": "total", "ID": "3", "SortOrder": "1", "color": "#005CA9","Category": "FLV"},
{"Percent": 0.295,"Team": "Team B", "type": "total", "ID": "3", "SortOrder": "1", "color": "#005CA9","Category": "KFZ"},
{"Percent": 0.055,"Team": "Team B", "type": "total", "ID": "3", "SortOrder": "1", "color": "#005CA9","Category": "KV"},
{"Percent": 0.025,"Team": "Team B", "type": "total", "ID": "3", "SortOrder": "1", "color": "#005CA9","Category": "LV"},
{"Percent": 0.051,"Team": "Team B", "type": "total", "ID": "3", "SortOrder": "1", "color": "#005CA9","Category": "RS"},
{"Percent": 0.2,"Team": "Team B", "type": "total", "ID": "3", "SortOrder": "1", "color": "#005CA9","Category": "SV"},
{"Percent": 0.063,"Team": "Team B", "type": "total", "ID": "3", "SortOrder": "1", "color": "#005CA9","Category": "UV"},
{"Percent": 0,"Team": "Team B", "type": "part", "ID": "3", "SortOrder": "2", "color": "#86C2EB","Category": "AH"},
{"Percent": 0,"Team": "Team B", "type": "part", "ID": "3", "SortOrder": "2", "color": "#86C2EB","Category": "FLV"},
{"Percent": 0.083,"Team": "Team B", "type": "part", "ID": "3", "SortOrder": "2", "color": "#86C2EB","Category": "KFZ"},
{"Percent": 0.042,"Team": "Team B", "type": "part", "ID": "3", "SortOrder": "2", "color": "#86C2EB","Category": "KV"},
{"Percent": 0.009,"Team": "Team B", "type": "part", "ID": "3", "SortOrder": "2", "color": "#86C2EB","Category": "LV"},
{"Percent": 0.014,"Team": "Team B", "type": "part", "ID": "3", "SortOrder": "2", "color": "#86C2EB","Category": "RS"},
{"Percent": 0.082,"Team": "Team B", "type": "part", "ID": "3", "SortOrder": "2", "color": "#86C2EB","Category": "SV"},
{"Percent": 0.023,"Team": "Team B", "type": "part", "ID": "3", "SortOrder": "2", "color": "#86C2EB","Category": "UV"},
{"Percent": 0,"Team": "Team C", "type": "total", "ID": "4", "SortOrder": "1", "color": "#005CA9","Category": "AH"},
{"Percent": 0,"Team": "Team C", "type": "total", "ID": "4", "SortOrder": "1", "color": "#005CA9","Category": "FLV"},
{"Percent": 0.004,"Team": "Team C", "type": "total", "ID": "4", "SortOrder": "1", "color": "#005CA9","Category": "KFZ"},
{"Percent": 0.006,"Team": "Team C", "type": "total", "ID": "4", "SortOrder": "1", "color": "#005CA9","Category": "KV"},
{"Percent": 0.002,"Team": "Team C", "type": "total", "ID": "4", "SortOrder": "1", "color": "#005CA9","Category": "LV"},
{"Percent": 0.001,"Team": "Team C", "type": "total", "ID": "4", "SortOrder": "1", "color": "#005CA9","Category": "RS"},
{"Percent": 0.003,"Team": "Team C", "type": "total", "ID": "4", "SortOrder": "1", "color": "#005CA9","Category": "SV"},
{"Percent": 0.003,"Team": "Team C", "type": "total", "ID": "4", "SortOrder": "1", "color": "#005CA9","Category": "UV"},
{"Percent": 0.001,"Team": "Team C", "type": "part", "ID": "4", "SortOrder": "2", "color": "#86C2EB","Category": "AH"},
{"Percent": 0.001,"Team": "Team C", "type": "part", "ID": "4", "SortOrder": "2", "color": "#86C2EB","Category": "FLV"},
{"Percent": 0.054,"Team": "Team C", "type": "part", "ID": "4", "SortOrder": "2", "color": "#86C2EB","Category": "KFZ"},
{"Percent": 0.068,"Team": "Team C", "type": "part", "ID": "4", "SortOrder": "2", "color": "#86C2EB","Category": "KV"},
{"Percent": 0.041,"Team": "Team C", "type": "part", "ID": "4", "SortOrder": "2", "color": "#86C2EB","Category": "LV"},
{"Percent": 0.012,"Team": "Team C", "type": "part", "ID": "4", "SortOrder": "2", "color": "#86C2EB","Category": "RS"},
{"Percent": 0.107,"Team": "Team C", "type": "part", "ID": "4", "SortOrder": "2", "color": "#86C2EB","Category": "SV"},
{"Percent": 0.086,"Team": "Team C", "type": "part", "ID": "4", "SortOrder": "2", "color": "#86C2EB","Category": "UV"}


    ]},
   
  "transform": [
    {
      "calculate": "1 * 0",
      "as": "Zero"
    },
    {"calculate": "1 * 1", "as": "One"}
  ],
 
  
  "encoding": {
    "y": {
      "field": "Team",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "axis": null,
      "sort": {
        "op": "sum",
        "field": "ID",
        "order": "ascending"
      }
    }
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "name": "BackgroundBAR",
      "mark": {
        "type": "bar",
        "color": "#DEE2E6",
        "height": 5,
        "cornerRadiusEnd": 4,
        "yOffset": 10
      },
      "encoding": {
        
        "x": {
          "field": "One",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "axis": {
            "title": null,
            "offset": 10,
            "tickCount": 5,
            "format": "0.0%"
          },
          "stack": false
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "BAR",
      "mark": {
        "type": "bar",
        "height": 5,
        "cornerRadiusEnd": 4,
        "yOffset": 10
      },
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "Percent",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "axis": null,
          "stack": true,
          "sort": {
            "op": "sum",
            "field": "SortOrder",
            "order": "ascending"
          }
        },
        "color": {
          "field": "type",
          "scale": {
            "range": {"field": "color"}
          },
          "type": "nominal",
          "legend": {
            "orient": "bottom",
            "title": null
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "text",
      "mark": {
        "type": "text",
        "align": "left",
        "color": "#005CA9",
        "font": "Segoe UI",
        "fontSize": 10,
        "fontStyle": "normal",
        "fontWeight": "bold"
      },
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "Zero",
          "type": "quantitative"
        },
        "text": {
          "field": "Team",
          "type": "nominal"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "DATA_LABEL",
      "mark": {
        "type": "text",
        "color": "#005CA9",
        "align": "left",
        "fontSize": 8,
        "font": "Segoe UI",
        "fontStyle": "normal",
        "fontWeight": "bold",
        "xOffset": 5,
        "yOffset": 20
      },
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "Percent",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "stack": true
        },
        "color": {
          "field": "type",
          "type": "nominal",
          "legend": {"orient": "bottom"}
        },
        "text": {
          "field": "Percent",
          "format": "0.0%"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
  
   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {
        "Percent": 0.001,
        "Team": "ALL",
        "type": "total",
        "ID": "1",
        "SortOrder": "1",
        "color": "#005CA9",
        "Category": "AH"
      },
      {
        "Percent": 0.001,
        "Team": "ALL",
        "type": "total",
        "ID": "1",
        "SortOrder": "1",
        "color": "#005CA9",
        "Category": "FLV"
      },
      {
        "Percent": 0.247,
        "Team": "ALL",
        "type": "total",
        "ID": "1",
        "SortOrder": "1",
        "color": "#005CA9",
        "Category": "KFZ"
      },
      {
        "Percent": 0.056,
        "Team": "ALL",
        "type": "total",
        "ID": "1",
        "SortOrder": "1",
        "color": "#005CA9",
        "Category": "KV"
      },
      {
        "Percent": 0.03,
        "Team": "ALL",
        "type": "total",
        "ID": "1",
        "SortOrder": "1",
        "color": "#005CA9",
        "Category": "LV"
      },
      {
        "Percent": 0.044,
        "Team": "ALL",
        "type": "total",
        "ID": "1",
        "SortOrder": "1",
        "color": "#005CA9",
        "Category": "RS"
      },
      {
        "Percent": 0.17,
        "Team": "ALL",
        "type": "total",
        "ID": "1",
        "SortOrder": "1",
        "color": "#005CA9",
        "Category": "SV"
      },
      {
        "Percent": 0.064,
        "Team": "ALL",
        "type": "total",
        "ID": "1",
        "SortOrder": "1",
        "color": "#005CA9",
        "Category": "UV"
      },
      {
        "Percent": 0.001,
        "Team": "ALL",
        "type": "part",
        "ID": "1",
        "SortOrder": "2",
        "color": "#86C2EB",
        "Category": "AH"
      },
      {
        "Percent": 0.001,
        "Team": "ALL",
        "type": "part",
        "ID": "1",
        "SortOrder": "2",
        "color": "#86C2EB",
        "Category": "FLV"
      },
      {
        "Percent": 0.067,
        "Team": "ALL",
        "type": "part",
        "ID": "1",
        "SortOrder": "2",
        "color": "#86C2EB",
        "Category": "KFZ"
      },
      {
        "Percent": 0.042,
        "Team": "ALL",
        "type": "part",
        "ID": "1",
        "SortOrder": "2",
        "color": "#86C2EB",
        "Category": "KV"
      },
      {
        "Percent": 0.015,
        "Team": "ALL",
        "type": "part",
        "ID": "1",
        "SortOrder": "2",
        "color": "#86C2EB",
        "Category": "LV"
      },
      {
        "Percent": 0.013,
        "Team": "ALL",
        "type": "part",
        "ID": "1",
        "SortOrder": "2",
        "color": "#86C2EB",
        "Category": "RS"
      },
      {
        "Percent": 0.077,
        "Team": "ALL",
        "type": "part",
        "ID": "1",
        "SortOrder": "2",
        "color": "#86C2EB",
        "Category": "SV"
      },
      {
        "Percent": 0.036,
        "Team": "ALL",
        "type": "part",
        "ID": "1",
        "SortOrder": "2",
        "color": "#86C2EB",
        "Category": "UV"
      },
      {
        "Percent": 0.001,
        "Team": "Team A",
        "type": "total",
        "ID": "2",
        "SortOrder": "1",
        "color": "#005CA9",
        "Category": "AH"
      },
      {
        "Percent": 0.002,
        "Team": "Team A",
        "type": "total",
        "ID": "2",
        "SortOrder": "1",
        "color": "#005CA9",
        "Category": "FLV"
      },
      {
        "Percent": 0.306,
        "Team": "Team A",
        "type": "total",
        "ID": "2",
        "SortOrder": "1",
        "color": "#005CA9",
        "Category": "KFZ"
      },
      {
        "Percent": 0.081,
        "Team": "Team A",
        "type": "total",
        "ID": "2",
        "SortOrder": "1",
        "color": "#005CA9",
        "Category": "KV"
      },
      {
        "Percent": 0.048,
        "Team": "Team A",
        "type": "total",
        "ID": "2",
        "SortOrder": "1",
        "color": "#005CA9",
        "Category": "LV"
      },
      {
        "Percent": 0.057,
        "Team": "Team A",
        "type": "total",
        "ID": "2",
        "SortOrder": "1",
        "color": "#005CA9",
        "Category": "RS"
      },
      {
        "Percent": 0.215,
        "Team": "Team A",
        "type": "total",
        "ID": "2",
        "SortOrder": "1",
        "color": "#005CA9",
        "Category": "SV"
      },
      {
        "Percent": 0.093,
        "Team": "Team A",
        "type": "total",
        "ID": "2",
        "SortOrder": "1",
        "color": "#005CA9",
        "Category": "UV"
      },
      {
        "Percent": 0.001,
        "Team": "Team A",
        "type": "part",
        "ID": "2",
        "SortOrder": "2",
        "color": "#86C2EB",
        "Category": "AH"
      },
      {
        "Percent": 0.001,
        "Team": "Team A",
        "type": "part",
        "ID": "2",
        "SortOrder": "2",
        "color": "#86C2EB",
        "Category": "FLV"
      },
      {
        "Percent": 0.055,
        "Team": "Team A",
        "type": "part",
        "ID": "2",
        "SortOrder": "2",
        "color": "#86C2EB",
        "Category": "KFZ"
      },
      {
        "Percent": 0.028,
        "Team": "Team A",
        "type": "part",
        "ID": "2",
        "SortOrder": "2",
        "color": "#86C2EB",
        "Category": "KV"
      },
      {
        "Percent": 0.01,
        "Team": "Team A",
        "type": "part",
        "ID": "2",
        "SortOrder": "2",
        "color": "#86C2EB",
        "Category": "LV"
      },
      {
        "Percent": 0.012,
        "Team": "Team A",
        "type": "part",
        "ID": "2",
        "SortOrder": "2",
        "color": "#86C2EB",
        "Category": "RS"
      },
      {
        "Percent": 0.056,
        "Team": "Team A",
        "type": "part",
        "ID": "2",
        "SortOrder": "2",
        "color": "#86C2EB",
        "Category": "SV"
      },
      {
        "Percent": 0.026,
        "Team": "Team A",
        "type": "part",
        "ID": "2",
        "SortOrder": "2",
        "color": "#86C2EB",
        "Category": "UV"
      },
      {
        "Percent": 0.001,
        "Team": "Team B",
        "type": "total",
        "ID": "3",
        "SortOrder": "1",
        "color": "#005CA9",
        "Category": "AH"
      },
      {
        "Percent": 0.001,
        "Team": "Team B",
        "type": "total",
        "ID": "3",
        "SortOrder": "1",
        "color": "#005CA9",
        "Category": "FLV"
      },
      {
        "Percent": 0.295,
        "Team": "Team B",
        "type": "total",
        "ID": "3",
        "SortOrder": "1",
        "color": "#005CA9",
        "Category": "KFZ"
      },
      {
        "Percent": 0.055,
        "Team": "Team B",
        "type": "total",
        "ID": "3",
        "SortOrder": "1",
        "color": "#005CA9",
        "Category": "KV"
      },
      {
        "Percent": 0.025,
        "Team": "Team B",
        "type": "total",
        "ID": "3",
        "SortOrder": "1",
        "color": "#005CA9",
        "Category": "LV"
      },
      {
        "Percent": 0.051,
        "Team": "Team B",
        "type": "total",
        "ID": "3",
        "SortOrder": "1",
        "color": "#005CA9",
        "Category": "RS"
      },
      {
        "Percent": 0.2,
        "Team": "Team B",
        "type": "total",
        "ID": "3",
        "SortOrder": "1",
        "color": "#005CA9",
        "Category": "SV"
      },
      {
        "Percent": 0.063,
        "Team": "Team B",
        "type": "total",
        "ID": "3",
        "SortOrder": "1",
        "color": "#005CA9",
        "Category": "UV"
      },
      {
        "Percent": 0,
        "Team": "Team B",
        "type": "part",
        "ID": "3",
        "SortOrder": "2",
        "color": "#86C2EB",
        "Category": "AH"
      },
      {
        "Percent": 0,
        "Team": "Team B",
        "type": "part",
        "ID": "3",
        "SortOrder": "2",
        "color": "#86C2EB",
        "Category": "FLV"
      },
      {
        "Percent": 0.083,
        "Team": "Team B",
        "type": "part",
        "ID": "3",
        "SortOrder": "2",
        "color": "#86C2EB",
        "Category": "KFZ"
      },
      {
        "Percent": 0.042,
        "Team": "Team B",
        "type": "part",
        "ID": "3",
        "SortOrder": "2",
        "color": "#86C2EB",
        "Category": "KV"
      },
      {
        "Percent": 0.009,
        "Team": "Team B",
        "type": "part",
        "ID": "3",
        "SortOrder": "2",
        "color": "#86C2EB",
        "Category": "LV"
      },
      {
        "Percent": 0.014,
        "Team": "Team B",
        "type": "part",
        "ID": "3",
        "SortOrder": "2",
        "color": "#86C2EB",
        "Category": "RS"
      },
      {
        "Percent": 0.082,
        "Team": "Team B",
        "type": "part",
        "ID": "3",
        "SortOrder": "2",
        "color": "#86C2EB",
        "Category": "SV"
      },
      {
        "Percent": 0.023,
        "Team": "Team B",
        "type": "part",
        "ID": "3",
        "SortOrder": "2",
        "color": "#86C2EB",
        "Category": "UV"
      },
      {
        "Percent": 0,
        "Team": "Team C",
        "type": "total",
        "ID": "4",
        "SortOrder": "1",
        "color": "#005CA9",
        "Category": "AH"
      },
      {
        "Percent": 0,
        "Team": "Team C",
        "type": "total",
        "ID": "4",
        "SortOrder": "1",
        "color": "#005CA9",
        "Category": "FLV"
      },
      {
        "Percent": 0.004,
        "Team": "Team C",
        "type": "total",
        "ID": "4",
        "SortOrder": "1",
        "color": "#005CA9",
        "Category": "KFZ"
      },
      {
        "Percent": 0.006,
        "Team": "Team C",
        "type": "total",
        "ID": "4",
        "SortOrder": "1",
        "color": "#005CA9",
        "Category": "KV"
      },
      {
        "Percent": 0.002,
        "Team": "Team C",
        "type": "total",
        "ID": "4",
        "SortOrder": "1",
        "color": "#005CA9",
        "Category": "LV"
      },
      {
        "Percent": 0.001,
        "Team": "Team C",
        "type": "total",
        "ID": "4",
        "SortOrder": "1",
        "color": "#005CA9",
        "Category": "RS"
      },
      {
        "Percent": 0.003,
        "Team": "Team C",
        "type": "total",
        "ID": "4",
        "SortOrder": "1",
        "color": "#005CA9",
        "Category": "SV"
      },
      {
        "Percent": 0.003,
        "Team": "Team C",
        "type": "total",
        "ID": "4",
        "SortOrder": "1",
        "color": "#005CA9",
        "Category": "UV"
      },
      {
        "Percent": 0.001,
        "Team": "Team C",
        "type": "part",
        "ID": "4",
        "SortOrder": "2",
        "color": "#86C2EB",
        "Category": "AH"
      },
      {
        "Percent": 0.001,
        "Team": "Team C",
        "type": "part",
        "ID": "4",
        "SortOrder": "2",
        "color": "#86C2EB",
        "Category": "FLV"
      },
      {
        "Percent": 0.054,
        "Team": "Team C",
        "type": "part",
        "ID": "4",
        "SortOrder": "2",
        "color": "#86C2EB",
        "Category": "KFZ"
      },
      {
        "Percent": 0.068,
        "Team": "Team C",
        "type": "part",
        "ID": "4",
        "SortOrder": "2",
        "color": "#86C2EB",
        "Category": "KV"
      },
      {
        "Percent": 0.041,
        "Team": "Team C",
        "type": "part",
        "ID": "4",
        "SortOrder": "2",
        "color": "#86C2EB",
        "Category": "LV"
      },
      {
        "Percent": 0.012,
        "Team": "Team C",
        "type": "part",
        "ID": "4",
        "SortOrder": "2",
        "color": "#86C2EB",
        "Category": "RS"
      },
      {
        "Percent": 0.107,
        "Team": "Team C",
        "type": "part",
        "ID": "4",
        "SortOrder": "2",
        "color": "#86C2EB",
        "Category": "SV"
      },
      {
        "Percent": 0.086,
        "Team": "Team C",
        "type": "part",
        "ID": "4",
        "SortOrder": "2",
        "color": "#86C2EB",
        "Category": "UV"
      }
    ]
  },
  "transform": [
    {"calculate": "1 * 0", "as": "Zero"},
    {"calculate": "1 * 1", "as": "One"}
  ],
  "facet": {"field": "Category", "type": "ordinal"},
  "spec": {
    "encoding": {
      "y": {
        "field": "Team",
        "type": "ordinal",
        "axis": null,
        "sort": {"op": "sum", "field": "ID", "order": "ascending"}
      }
    },
    "layer": [
      {
        "name": "BackgroundBAR",
        "mark": {
          "type": "bar",
          "color": "#DEE2E6",
          "height": 5,
          "cornerRadiusEnd": 4,
          "yOffset": 10
        },
        "encoding": {
          "x": {
            "field": "One",
            "type": "quantitative",
            "axis": {
              "title": null,
              "offset": 10,
              "tickCount": 5,
              "format": "0.0%"
            },
            "stack": false
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "BAR",
        "mark": {
          "type": "bar",
          "height": 5,
          "cornerRadiusEnd": 4,
          "yOffset": 10
        },
        "encoding": {
          "x": {
            "field": "Percent",
            "type": "quantitative",
            "axis": null,
            "stack": true,
            "sort": {"op": "sum", "field": "SortOrder", "order": "ascending"}
          },
          "color": {
            "field": "type",
            "type": "nominal",
            "legend": {"orient": "bottom", "title": null}
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "text",
        "mark": {
          "type": "text",
          "align": "left",
          "color": "#005CA9",
          "font": "Segoe UI",
          "fontSize": 10,
          "fontStyle": "normal",
          "fontWeight": "bold"
        },
        "encoding": {
          "x": {"field": "Zero", "type": "quantitative"},
          "text": {"field": "Team", "type": "nominal"}
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "DATA_LABEL",
        "mark": {
          "type": "text",
          "color": "#005CA9",
          "align": "left",
          "fontSize": 8,
          "font": "Segoe UI",
          "fontStyle": "normal",
          "fontWeight": "bold",
          "xOffset": 5,
          "yOffset": 20
        },
        "encoding": {
          "x": {"field": "Percent", "type": "quantitative", "stack": true},
          "color": {
            "field": "type",
            "type": "nominal",
            "legend": {"orient": "bottom"}
          },
          "text": {"field": "Percent", "format": "0.0%"}
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```